# Static progress bar in ios

Tags: ios, progress-bar

I am trying to implement a static progress bar which will show the percentage and just stay as it is. It will change as the data changes.

```
progressPercent = @(([currentlocation.loyaltyCredit floatValue] / [currentlocation.loyaltySpendAmount floatValue]) * 100);

[ProgressView setProgress:[progressPercent floatValue]];
```

The first line is setting the percentage to 10.
When I run this, all I see is the 100% progress bar.
Can you help me out?

Comment: From where did you get the idea that `UIProgressView` expects the progress to be specified in percents, whereas the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006782-CH3-SW2) clearly states that it is not the case?

Comment: Side note: Why do you create the `NSNumber *progressPercent` just to extract its floating point value?

Comment: @MartinR I am pretty new to ios, so this was the only way to make it work with JSON data.

Comment: Have you looked at cocoa controls website? They have lots of controls that you can implement in your project. One of them may fit your needs. Do searches on that site like "percentage, progress bars etc" https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=✓&q=percentage

Answer (score 2):

To be more explicit than H2CO3:

From the docs on UIProgressView:

> Discussion The current progress is represented by a floating-point
>   **value between 0.0 and 1.0**, inclusive, where 1.0 indicates the
>   completion of the task. The default value is 0.0. Values less than 0.0
>   and greater than 1.0 are pinned to those limits.

BTW, what do you mean "static" progress bar? And "stay as it is?" Isn't the point of a progress bar to display a progress bar that varies from 0 to 1? If it's static, how can it display a varying value? If "It will change as the data changes" then it's not really static, is it?

You need to work on both your posting skills and on learning to use the documentation. Don't run to the forums until you actually read the docs on a given subject, and still can't figure out what's going on after a real, concerted effort. Otherwise you will quickly burn through the goodwill of the people best able to help you and people will start ignoring you as lazy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was the only way I could think of to tell what I wanted. I want a progress bar that shows a current percentage and keeps showing it until the data changes which means closing the page to allow another connection to JSON data.

Comment: A progress bar is a view object that displays a value. If you change the value, it changes the progress level that it shows. If you want it to stay static, don't change the value.